# «Пресечь свалку, пока не поздно». Верна запятая?

Tags: запятые

«Пресечь свалку, пока не поздно». Верна запятая? «Пока» ведь союз....

Comment: Как можно "пресечь свалку"...

Answer (score 1):

Да, союз, который открывает придаточное предложение времени.

Придаточные времени прикрепляются к главному предложению союзами: *когда, **пока**, покамест, прежде чем, как только, как, как вдруг, едва, в то время как, с тех пор как, до тех пор как, по мере того как* и др.

См. СПП: [Придаточные времени](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/745-233_pridatochnye_vremeni.html).